# How to find the size of video RAM in any android device?

Tags: android, video, graphics, textures, ram

How do I get to know the size of video RAM in any android device so that I can load textures based on the size? The maximum size of texture is 4096 X 4096. What relation does it have to the size in bytes of the image (i.e. on bytes per pixel) ?

I want to find the size of Video RAM based on which I can decide how many textures can I load in memory at a time for optimal performance... i.e. no of textures = memory size / size (in bytes) of one texture

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly comment so I'll have to make do with this.

I don't know why you're referring to video RAM, and I'm quite unclear about what you're asking based on screen size by using nine patch images:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

But you can also put images in their respected screen size folders (-hdpi, -ldpi, etc) and android will automatically choose the image according to the screen size.

And again, I'm quite unclear about what you're asking, so if you were to clarify what you are trying to do people will be able to help you better.

Comment: Ok..I want to find the size of Video RAM based on which I can decide how many textures can I load in memory at a time for optimal performance...

i.e. no of textures = memory size / size (in bytes )of one texture


i hope it is clear now... :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's posible to find the size of video RAM but there are some devices that don't support any size of texture.

For example, GPU of Galaxy tab 2 (PowerVR SGX540) don't support textures bigger than 2048x2048 so it's posible that your 4096x4096 texture can not be showed in some devices.